# The subscript is outside the error range 800A0009

Tags: vbscript

I changed a computer with XP to w10 and a script that works with win WP gives me error of "the subscript is out of range" with W10. It gives me this error in the line "Set f = fso.GetFolder (objArgs (0))".

Then I copy the script:

```
enter code here


'**************************************************************** 
'* Script Comprueba si hay archivos, ejecuta proceso y renombra *
'**************************************************************** 

 '*** Declaro variables y creo objetos necesarios *** 

Dim Ejecuta, return 
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments 
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

'*** Bucle de Cambio de nombre 
Set f = fso.GetFolder(objArgs(0)) 
Set fc = f.Files 
For Each f1 in fc

'*** Tratar los ficheros del directorio
nounom = "VACIO"

'*** JCT SI QUIERES TRATAR TODOS LOS FICHEROS DEL DIRECTORIO ELIMINA ESTA                       

If Left(UCase(f1.Name),3)= "ORD" Then 

'*** PROCESAR FICHERO LEIDO
'WScript.Echo "procesar archivo leido"
 command = "%COMSPEC% /k " 

 dos_command = "startrfc -3 -d DAP -u edi -p dav543 -c 100 -l ES -h    10.10.20.2 -s 00 -E PATHNAME=\\10.10.53.2\EDI\VOXEL\IN\"+f1.Name+ " -E PORT=DVG -F EDI_DATA_INCOMING -t"
'MsgBox dos_command

 ' Execute command.
 WshShell.Run(command + dos_command)

 'MsgBox "Fichero Procesado " + f1.Name

 '*** nounom es el nombre del nuevo fichero
 nounom = f1.name+".bak"

 '*** ubinounom es la ubicacion y el nombre del nuevo fichero
 ubinounom = "\\10.10.53.2\EDI\VOXEL\IN\"&nounom 

 '*** JCT SI QUIERES TRATAT TODOS LOS FICHEROS DEL DIRECTORIO ELIMINA ESTA INSTRUCCION Y LA 'SIGUIENTE
 End If     

 '*** Comprobar si existe el fichero de destino, si no existe cambiar de nombre el de origen y 'moverlo a carpeta destino 
 If nounom <> "VACIO" and not(fso.FileExists(ubinounom)) Then
 fso.CopyFile "\\daesvpfs01\EDI\voxel\IN\"&f1.Name,    "\\daesvpfs01\EDI\voxel\HISTORICO\"&nounom

 End if

 Next
```

Comment: When you are running the vbs file, are you providing the command line arguments?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "the subscript is out of range" error when using objArgs(0), it is simply because objArgs does not contains anything. It has nothing to do with the OS. It is probably because you did not pass the required argument to your script. It is a good practice to check for missing arguments and report an error. You could add something like that to your code:

```
If objArgs.Count = 0 then
    WScript.echo "Missing argument."
    WScript.Quit
End if
```

To fix your problem, take a look at how you call your script. It should be something like:

```
cscript scriptfilename.vbs foldername
```

You are probably currently missing the foldername argument.